# add element in vector built by struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

my C++ might include multi-error... the first one is how to add struct element in a vector

my code will be like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct eMailMsg {
string to; // i.e. "professor@stanford.edu"
string from; // i.e. "student@stanford.edu"
string message; // body of message
string subject; // i.e. "CS106 Rocks!"
int date; // date email was sent
int time; // time email was sent
};

int main(){
    vector <eMailMsg> mailVector;
    mailVector[0]={"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message",4,16};
    for( std::vector<eMailMsg>::const_iterator i = mailVector.begin(); i != mailVector.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: mailVector[0]={"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message",4,16}; This statement is correct or not? @Mohammed Majeed

Comment: @BenSeedangie You haven't allocated the vector with elements. Thus accessing the address `&mailVector[0]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: What is `system("pasuse");`? ;)

Comment: Also `cout << *i` can't work since you don't define how it should be printed (i.e. there is no [overload for `operator<<`](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/))

Comment: 0x499602D2 what the exact syntax look like if I would like to add those information to mailVector? should I use push_back??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To add an element to a vector, there is [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

   ```
   mailVector.push_back({"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message",4,16});
   ```

   The braces construct a new `eMailMsg` when passed to the function. [See a working code here.](http://ideone.com/KdxsgO)

   Your syntax is used to **replace** an element with a new value (assignment).

   Since C++11 we also have [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which is slightly more efficient. The function `push_back` copies or moves an existing object into the vector. But `emplace_back` constructs it "in place" with the provided constructor arguments. It is provided the constructor arguments:

   ```
   mailVector.emplace_back("professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message",4,16);
   ```

   A third way (not recommended) is to first resize the vector to a given size (`std::vector::resize`, or initially in the constructor) and then using the assignment syntax you've used in your code.
2. You forgot one initializer (argument) for the construction of an `eMailMsg` object: the subject.
3. To print a value of a custom type (in your case an `eMailMsg`) using `std::cout`, you need to overload the streaming operator. A typical implementation uses the provided stream to print several things, and then returns the stream for concatenation of multiple values in one line:

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, eMailMsg &mail) {
       // Print only "to" and "from" for demonstration.
       return out << "To: " << mail.to << "\nFrom: " << mail.from << "\n";
   }
   ```
4. [Never use `system("pause");`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Comment: Actually, I would like to print the elements in vector mailVector. It seems that you code is work for printing the struct content. Correct me, if I was wrong. THank you!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to print. The elements in the vector **are** structs, and printing them only works if **you** define how it should be done. My answer demonstrates this by printing the receiver and sender address in two lines, but you might want to have something else...

Answer (score 5):

you put something in a vector with the `.push_back()` method, so for starters:

```
mailVector.pushBack(...)
```

code:

```
eMailMsg myMailMsg = {"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message", 4, 16};
mailVector.pushBack(myMailMsg);
```

Comment: `mailVector.push_back("professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message",4,16);` Like this??

Comment: I've edited my response with the code!

Comment: Actually you don't need the variable. You can simply put the constructor args with the braces in `push_back`. (Like in my answer)

Comment: +1 for that, but maybe it would be simpler for him to understand with a variable if he is a beginner!

Comment: @IvanPavičić Good argument. ;)

Comment: Off-topic: While suggesting edits to posts please remove the salutations as well. But just don't edit post to remove them.